# Numerical stability on the solution of first order linear equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

Suppose
$$
\begin{cases}
\frac{dy}{dt}+ay=g(t),\\y(0)=y_0=g(0)/a,\\\dot{y}(0)=0
\end{cases}
$$
Then the solution has the form
$$
y=e^{-at}\bigg(\int_0^te^{as}g(s)ds+y_0\bigg)
$$
The issue is that I only have a discrete sampling for $g(t)$ at 1000 Hz, so I am solving $y$ with numerical integration.
But when I try, the solution diverges significantly (to the scale of 1e+256) because of $e^{-at}$ when $a<0$.

When I verify the result, the original equation is violated.

Is there a more stable way to solve the equation?

The scale of $a$ is approximately $-100$, and I am solving for a period of at least 10 s. $g(t)$ is bounded, i.e., $|g(t)|<100$.